# Function naming convention when with qualifiers: adj+verb, verb+adv or adv+verb?

Tags: standards, naming, conventions

For example, for names comprehensiveInspect, inspectComprehensively, and comprehensivelyInspect, which to choose?

'inspectComprehensively' obeys syntax, but I have never seen a function name ending with an adverbial.

Answer (score 1):

You only need "comprehensively" if it's an option. Otherwise, you document that the inspection is comprehensive.

```swift
func inspect(comprehensively comprehensive: Bool = true)
```